# Virtuozzo Kickstart with post-installation

Tags: virtuozzo

I have problem with post-installation on kickstart Virtuozzo. Using kickstart, I can install OS Virtuozzo normally. But after I try to add with post-installation script, there is problem on script prl .

Below is my script post-installation:

```
%post --log=/root/ks-post.log

# delete all virtual network
while true; do prlsrvctl net list | awk {'print $1}' | tail -n +2 | while read line; do prlsrvctl net del $line; done && echo -e "$(date)\tSuccess" && break; echo -e "$(date)\tFailed"; systemctl status prl-disp.service; sleep 15; done

# delete all interface include bridge network
brctl show| awk {'print $1'}| tail -n +2| while read line; do ip link set $line down && brctl delbr $line; done
nmcli c s|awk {'print $1'}| tail -n +2| while read line; do nmcli c down $line && ip link set $line nomaster && nmcli c d $line; done
#ip a| awk -F: {'print $2'}| grep 'br\|enp'| awk -F @ {'print $1'}| while read line; do ip link set $line down; done
#ip a| awk -F: {'print $2'}| grep enp| awk -F @ {'print $1'}| while read line; do ip link set $line nomaster; done

# create virtual network
for net in net01 net02 net03; do prlsrvctl net add $net; done

# create interface
nmcli c a type vlan con-name enp2s0f0.501 dev enp2s0f0 id 501 master virbr2
nmcli c a type ethernet con-name enp2s0f0 ifname enp2s0f0 master virbr1
nmcli c a type ethernet con-name enp2s0f1 ifname enp2s0f0 master virbr3
nmcli c s| grep bridge| awk {'print $1'}| while read line; do nmcli c m $line connection.autoconnect yes ipv4.method auto bridge.stp yes bridge.forward-delay 15; done

# delete ip link virbr#-nic
ip a| awk -F: {'print $2'}| grep nic| while read line; do ip link del $line; done

# restart network
systemctl restart network

# up2date
yum update -y; yum install epel-release -y; yum update -y

# set hostname
dig -x 192.168.75.206 +short |sed 's/.$//' > /etc/hostname; hostname -F /etc/hostname
echo "hostname changed. below is the hostname"
cat /etc/hostname

# reboot
reboot
%end
```

When I check log, there are problem with command prl. these is like prl-disp are not running.

```
Login failed: Unable to connect to Virtuozzo. You may experience a connection problem or the server may be down. Contact your Virtuozzo administrator for assistance.
Virtual network has been deleted
Connection 'enp2s0f0' successfully deactivated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0)
Error: 'enp2s0f0' is not an active connection.
Error: no active connection provided.
Error: 'enp2s0f1' is not an active connection.
Error: no active connection provided.
Interface are cleaned
Login failed: Unable to connect to Virtuozzo. You may experience a connection problem or the server may be down. Contact your Virtuozzo administrator for assistance.
Login failed: Unable to connect to Virtuozzo. You may experience a connection problem or the server may be down. Contact your Virtuozzo administrator for assistance.
Login failed: Unable to connect to Virtuozzo. You may experience a connection problem or the server may be down. Contact your Virtuozzo administrator for assistance.
virtual network virtuozzo are created
Warning: master='virbr2' doesn't refer to any existing profile.
Error: Failed to add 'enp2s0f0.501' connection: connection.slave-type: Cannot set 'master' without 'slave-type'
Warning: master='virbr1' doesn't refer to any existing profile.
Error: Failed to add 'enp2s0f0' connection: connection.slave-type: Cannot set 'master' without 'slave-type'
Warning: master='virbr3' doesn't refer to any existing profile.
Error: Failed to add 'enp2s0f1' connection: connection.slave-type: Cannot set 'master' without 'slave-type'
interface are prepared, restart network for discover an IP address
interface virbr with nic has been deleted
Running in chroot, ignoring request.
network restarted
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, priorities, product-id, refresh-
              : packagekit, rhsm-auto-add-pools, search-disabled-repos, shaman,
              : virtuozzo, vzlinux, yum-plugin-readykernel
Unable to send message to PackageKit
Trying to discover and attach new pools


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: virtuozzo-os
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://repo.virtuozzo.com/vz/mirrorlists/7.0/releases-os.mirrorlist error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: repo.virtuozzo.com; Unknown error"
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, priorities, product-id, refresh-
              : packagekit, rhsm-auto-add-pools, search-disabled-repos, shaman,
              : virtuozzo, vzlinux, yum-plugin-readykernel
Unable to send message to PackageKit
Trying to discover and attach new pools


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: virtuozzo-os
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://repo.virtuozzo.com/vz/mirrorlists/7.0/releases-os.mirrorlist error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: repo.virtuozzo.com; Unknown error"
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, priorities, product-id, refresh-
              : packagekit, rhsm-auto-add-pools, search-disabled-repos, shaman,
              : virtuozzo, vzlinux, yum-plugin-readykernel
Unable to send message to PackageKit
Trying to discover and attach new pools


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: virtuozzo-os
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://repo.virtuozzo.com/vz/mirrorlists/7.0/releases-os.mirrorlist error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: repo.virtuozzo.com; Unknown error"
hostname: the specified hostname is invalid
hostname changed. below is the hostname

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-38.vl7.2 <<>> -x 192.168.75.206 +shor
;; global options: +cm
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reache
Running in chroot, ignoring request.
```

The constraint made my configuration not working properly.

From the post-installation, is there any command / configuration should I do? Right now I'm just learning it. So I really need some clue in order to understand the cause of this problem.

Sorry for my bad english, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to answer but hopefully this helps someone.  You do not state which version of Virtuozzo you are attempting to install, but I will assume Virtuozzo 7 as I would not personally be building any new systems with Virtuozzo 6.

The errors you posted seem to show that you have no network configured during the post install, and I can see in your postinstall actions you are disabling the network and it is not getting setup again.  This prevents prl-disp from working and does not allow prlsrvctl to run afterwards (though it does work in the step where you remove all default Virtuozzo bridges).  This is also the cause of the YUM errors at the end.

You have lots of actions in your post install that should be handled with standard kickstart options.

The hostname, network devices, and all nmcli should be handled using the "network" option in [kickstart](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/sect-kickstart-syntax).

A better approach would be to use the default GUI installer to manually configure a system, and once you have an install you can work with, you would take the resulting kickstart (should be located at /root/original-ks.cfg on the newly installed system) and then add your special sauce in the postinstall.  This way you start with a base kickstart that is known to work and knows all your network device names, then add your customizations.